# Python, Pandas Dataframe, column that has the summation of whatever before it and starts over for new projects in df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have this DF and I am trying to get total books for whatever that's before the row and have the same `workDate` and `ID`. If  either `workDate` or `ID` change then total should start over as in my example.

I am sorting my DF by `ID` and then by `workDate`

```
|   |workDate   |ID       | Books# | Seller |    
|-------------------------------------------|
| 0 |2020-01-09 |13702    | 10.0   |  Ted   |
| 1 |2020-01-09 |13702    | 20.5   |  Sam   |   
| 2 |2020-01-10 |13702    | 22.0   |  Lili  |   
| 3 |2020-01-10 |13702    | 10.0   |  Ted   |    
| 4 |2020-01-10 |13702    | 30.0   |  John  |  
| 5 |2020-01-10 |23703    | 20.0   |  Fadi  |   
| 6 |2020-01-10 |23703    | 15.0   |  Mo    |    
| 7 |2020-01-10 |23703    | 8.0    |  Samer |
```

Desired output:

```
|   |workDate   |ID       | Books# |  totalBooks  | Seller |    
|----------------------------------------------------------|
| 0 |2020-01-09 |13702    | 10.0   |    10.0      |  Ted   |
| 1 |2020-01-09 |13702    | 20.5   |    30.5      |  Sam   |    
| 2 |2021-01-10 |13702    | 22.0   |    22.0      |  Lili  |    
| 3 |2021-01-10 |13702    | 10.0   |    32.0      |  Ted   |    
| 4 |2021-01-10 |13702    | 30.0   |    62.0      |  John  |  
| 5 |2021-01-10 |23703    | 20.0   |    20.0      |  Fadi  |    
| 6 |2021-01-10 |23703    | 15.0   |    35.0      |  Mo    |    
| 7 |2021-01-10 |23703    | 8.0    |    43.0      |  Samer |
```

I have tried multiple ways of grouping by but I was not able to get to desired output. I am able to get a total column for all values but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use [`groupby cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) get cumulative sum of `Books#` per `workDate` and `ID` pair:

```
df['totalBooks'] = df.groupby(['workDate', 'ID'])['Books#'].cumsum()
```

`df`:

```
     workDate     ID  Books# Seller  totalBooks
0  2020-01-09  13702    10.0    Ted        10.0
1  2020-01-09  13702    20.5    Sam        30.5
2  2020-01-10  13702    22.0   Lili        22.0
3  2020-01-10  13702    10.0    Ted        32.0
4  2020-01-10  13702    30.0   John        62.0
5  2020-01-10  23703    20.0   Fadi        20.0
6  2020-01-10  23703    15.0     Mo        35.0
7  2020-01-10  23703     8.0  Samer        43.0
```

---

Or with [`insert`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) to get in the correct place:

```
df.insert(3, 'totalBooks', df.groupby(['workDate', 'ID'])['Books#'].cumsum())
```

`df`:

```
    workDate     ID  Books#  totalBooks Seller
0 2020-01-09  13702    10.0        10.0    Ted
1 2020-01-09  13702    20.5        30.5    Sam
2 2020-01-10  13702    22.0        22.0   Lili
3 2020-01-10  13702    10.0        32.0    Ted
4 2020-01-10  13702    30.0        62.0   John
5 2020-01-10  23703    20.0        20.0   Fadi
6 2020-01-10  23703    15.0        35.0     Mo
7 2020-01-10  23703     8.0        43.0  Samer
```

---

DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'workDate': pd.to_datetime(['2020-01-09', '2020-01-09', '2020-01-10',
                                '2020-01-10', '2020-01-10', '2020-01-10',
                                '2020-01-10', '2020-01-10']),
    'ID': [13702, 13702, 13702, 13702, 13702, 23703, 23703, 23703],
    'Books#': [10.0, 20.5, 22.0, 10.0, 30.0, 20.0, 15.0, 8.0],
    'Seller': ['Ted', 'Sam', 'Lili', 'Ted', 'John', 'Fadi', 'Mo', 'Samer']
})
```